# Joining 2 dataframes on more than one column without duplicate columns in result dataframe - Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider DataFrame A with columns x, y, z and DataFrame B with columns x, y, w

I want to (inner) join DataFrames A and B on both the columns x and y with the resulting dataframe containing x,y,z,w and not x,x,y,y,z,w

Could someone please advise how to do this in JAVA? Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

After join, drop the duplicate columns using `drop` function. The `drop` function takes column name as well as column object. You can't use column name because its duplicate. See how I have used column object.

```
    dataframeA.join(dataFrameB,dataframeA("x") === dataFrameB("x") && 
                   dataFrameB,dataframeA("y") === dataFrameB("y"),"inner"
                   ).drop(dataframeA("x")).drop(dataframeA("y"))
```